# How do you deal with different screen/browser sizes?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website for myself (portfolio to be precise) and I have some images that I want to put in the website.

I was coding on my laptop (15") and previewing the website there all the time. I then uploaded it to a server and opened it on my home pc (23" screen), first thing I noticed was that all the images are way too small for this kind of screen.

Images looked perfectly fine and occupied about 60% of the screen height on my laptop while they hardly occupy 40% of my 23" screen.

How do you website designers deal with this kind of stuff?

Comment: Google "responsive web design" and check out the first few links.

Comment: CSS Media Queries can be pretty helpful in restricting your design based on viewport, large screens can have plenty of flair, smaller screens just get content. Then it can be useful to every audience, even smartphones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responsive web design along with media queries is the way to go.

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-tutorials/